# Driving activity confidence is low all time in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11, core-motion

I've an application which **detects user driving** and do some process internally. After the iOS update from iOS-10 to iOS-11, the application stops working. Still the application **works great in iOS 10**, but **fails in iOS 11**.

After debugging I found that the **CMMotionActivityManager** had the issue. The confidence of the **automotive** activity is **low (0)** at most of the time even though the user is actually driving.

Since this I can't identify the complete driving behaviour of the user.

Here is the sample code I'm using.

```
if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
    motion.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {
        activityData
        in
        self.handleActivityData(activityData!)
    })
}

func handleActivityData(_ activityData: CMMotionActivity) {
    let rawConfidence = activityData.confidence.rawValue
    // Confidence = 2  -> high
    // Confidence = 0  -> low
    if rawConfidence > 0 {
        if activityData.automotive {
            drivingActivity = true
            Log.info("Activity : Automotive")
        } else {
            drivingActivity = false
            var text = "Empty"
            if activityData.walking {
                text = "Walking"
            } else if activityData.running {
                text = "Running"
            } else if activityData.stationary {
                text = "Stationary"
            } else if activityData.cycling {
                text = "Cycling"
            } else if activityData.unknown {
                text = "Unknown"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do anyone face the same issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am facing same issue did you find any solution

Comment: Nothing dude, no luck still

Comment: I am also facing the same issue have you find a solution?

Comment: Nothing yet...!